# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server

when I run this query I get the following error at line 49 that is insert into #info_rep, can anyone tell me what did I do wrong? I think the problem is at file number ,but why?
[image: Error message]

```
drop table #info_rep

create table #info_rep
(
    number int,
    nume varchar(64),
    "file number" varchar(32),
    "y" varchar(32),
    "z" varchar(32),
    "c" varchar(32),
    "v" varchar(32),
    "b" varchar(32),
    "a" varchar(32),
    "d" varchar(32),
    "f" varchar(32),
    "g" varchar(32),
    "h" varchar(32),
    "q" varchar(32),
    "w" varchar(32),
    "e" varchar(32),
    "r" varchar(32),
    "t" varchar(32),
    "y" varchar(32)
)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
   
select distinct(number_field1), transaction_id
from tg 
where 1=1
AND ddate IS NULL
and number_field1 in (select id from cpty)
and flag = 'IE'
and id in (
    select _id from
    dbo.[tn] WITH (NOLOCK)
    where start_date between LTRIM(RTRIM('2021'))   +'-'+ 
        LTRIM(RTRIM('01')) +'-'+ LTRIM(RTRIM('01')) 
    AND LTRIM(RTRIM('2021')) +'-'+ 
        LTRIM(RTRIM('12')) +'-'+ LTRIM(RTRIM('30'))
)
order by 2; 

DECLARE @tid int;
DECLARE @nf INT;

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nf, @tid;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nf, @tid;

    insert into #info_rep 

    ----//////////////////////////////////////////

    SELECT convert(varchar,t.ts)"file number" ,
        (case when (
            select top 1 text_field10
            from tg 
            where 1=1
            AND ddate IS NULL
            AND text_field10 is not null
            AND id =  @tid
            and number_field1= @nf
            ORDER BY tg_id DESC )
        is null then (
            select cpty_sht+' '+cpty_nm+' '+ccpty_nm2
            from cpty      
            where cptyy_id=@nf
        )
        else (
            select top 1 text_field10
            from tg 
            where 1=1
            AND ddate IS NULL
            AND text_field10 is not null
            AND id =  @tid
            and number_field1= @nf
            ORDER BY tg_id DESC
        ) end) "nume" 
    FROM [t] t  WITH (NOLOCK)
    where t.t_id=@tid        

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @nf, @tid;
END;

CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;

select * from #info_rep
```

Comment: Side issue, but why do you have 2 FETCH statements inside your cursor?

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the column names for the insert statement.

```
insert into #info_rep([file number], nume)
```

Comment: I did it but still the "file number" column doesn't display any results,it's either null either displays results from the next column...

Comment: @DeusTerrae: You can post a new question since that looks like a totally different problem, even though it apparently relates to the same task you are working on.  This answer shows how to resolve the issue you asked about in this thread.  For your other issue it would seem best to start a new one.